# ssl certificate for GSM Modem

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, ssl-certificate, tcp

Im working on a Quectel M10 GSM modem where im supposed to establish a TCP/IP connection over SSL/TSL. The M10 Manual describes the process of adding the Certificates. My problem is that I dont know how to proceed. Following is the command:

```
     AT+QSECWRITE="RAM:ca_cert.pem",1614,100
     <input the ca_cert.pem data here size is 1614bytes.>
```

where 1614 is length of data and 100 is input time for writing the data.
After executing the command in the serial window, I have to enter the data.After which the certificates will be store in the RAM of modem.
Now i dont know what the ca_cert.pem file is and where to get it from.
There are 2 more commands to be executed

```
     AT+QSECWRITE="RAM:client_cert.pem",1419,100
     input the client_cert.pem data here size is 1419bytes
     AT+QSECWRITE="RAM:client_key.pem",1679,100
     <input the client_key.pem data here size is 1679bytes.>
```

Could anyone please explain me how to proceed further with this and how to establish SSl connection.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I have the same module, but it returns an error whenever I execute any SSL function.

Answer (score 1):

It's asking for your SSL certificate.

Usually a device should have SSL/TLS encryption to support HTTPS function.
So the module wants you to upload the CA certificate, Client certificate, and Client key to its RAM.